# Not able to attach click event to an Anchor tag inside a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Below is my code 
ComponentA.js

return statement inside the component

```
 return (
       ......

        <a id="MytoolTip" ......  

       <ComponentB
          content={
            `
            <div class="share_cart_tt">
                  <a 
                  data-automation-id="..."
                  class="callFunction" 
                   > Invite </a>
            </div>
           `
          }
          target={'MytoolTip'}
          closeButton
       />

);
```

ComponentB.js (this is a tooltip which will be displayed when user clicks on anchor tag MytoolTip)

```
.....

class ComponentB extends Component {
  launchModal() {
    console.log("hey its fine");
  }
     ...
      renderContent = () => {
          document.getElementsByClassName('callFunction').
          addEventListener('click', this.launchModal);
      **I am trying to bind click event here but its not working out**
     }

}
```

I am beginner to react and I tried different methods to bind the click event but nothing worked out.. need help.
When the user click on the anchor tag inside the tooltip with class .callFunction console.log should be printed.

**Please note that I am trying to add onClick event to the anchor tag, which is just a static content in ComponentA and a tooltip will be created by getting static content in prop.content in ComponentB**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React components have [synthetic event listeners](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).  All you need to do is add the `onClick` property to the element. So yours would look like this:

```
return (
       ......

        <a id="MytoolTip" ......  

       <ComponentB
          content={
            `
            <div class="share_cart_tt">
                  <a 
                  data-automation-id="..."
                  onClick={FunctionToBeCalledWhenClicked}
                  class="callFunction" 
                   > Invite </a>
            </div>
           `
          }
          target={'MytoolTip'}
          closeButton
       />

);
```

Comment: I think you''ll need preventDefault since to override the default behaviour of navigation

Comment: Yes, OP will need to `preventDefault()` in the function being called. I didn't add that to my answer as the question was asked only about how to add the event listener, not what to do with the event after it was triggered.

Comment: @technicallynick.. i already tried this onClick one. It had given error 'launchShareCartModal is not defined'

Comment: I'd have to see the rest of your component (not just render) to try to help you with it. Perhaps it's `this.launchShareCartModal`?